# Access denied error while mounting a shared folder?

Tags: 12.04, mount, nfs, mountpoint

I am a linux newbie and I have a very basic question. I have three machines -

```
machineA    10.108.24.132
machineB    10.108.24.133
machineC    10.108.24.134
```

and all those machines have Ubuntu 12.04 installed in it and I have root access to all those three machines.

Now I am supposed to do below things in my above machines -

```
Create mount point /opt/exhibitor/conf
Mount the directory in all servers.
 sudo mount <NFS-SERVER>:/opt/exhibitor/conf /opt/exhibitor/conf/
```

I have already created `/opt/exhibitor/conf` directory in all those three machines as mentioned above.

Now I am trying to create a Mount Point on all those three machines. So I followed the below process -

Install NFS support files and NFS kernel server in all the above three machines

```
$ sudo apt-get install nfs-common nfs-kernel-server
```

Create the shared directory in all the above three machines

```
$ mkdir /opt/exhibitor/conf/
```

Edited the `/etc/exports` and added the entry like this in all the above three machines -

```
# /etc/exports: the access control list for filesystems which may be exported
#               to NFS clients.  See exports(5).
#
# Example for NFSv2 and NFSv3:
# /srv/homes       hostname1(rw,sync,no_subtree_check) hostname2(ro,sync,no_subtree_check)
#
# Example for NFSv4:
# /srv/nfs4        gss/krb5i(rw,sync,fsid=0,crossmnt,no_subtree_check)
# /srv/nfs4/homes  gss/krb5i(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
#
/opt/exhibitor/conf/     10.108.24.*(rw)
```

Run exportfs in all the above three machines

```
root@machineA:/# exportfs -rv
exportfs: /etc/exports [1]: Neither 'subtree_check' or 'no_subtree_check' specified for export "10.108.24.*:/opt/exhibitor/conf/".
  Assuming default behaviour ('no_subtree_check').
  NOTE: this default has changed since nfs-utils version 1.0.x

exporting 10.108.24.*:/opt/exhibitor/conf
```

Now I did `showmount` on `machineA`

```
root@machineA:/# showmount -e 10.108.24.132
Export list for 10.108.24.132:
/opt/exhibitor/conf 10.108.24.*
```

And also I have started the NFS server like this in all the above three machines -

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server start
```

And now when I did this, I am getting an error -

```
root@machineA:/# sudo mount -t nfs 10.108.24.132:/opt/exhibitor/conf /opt/exhibitor/conf/
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 10.108.24.132:/opt/exhibitor/conf
```

I have also tried doing the same thing from machineB and machineC as well and still I get the same error-

```
root@machineB:/# sudo mount -t nfs 10.108.24.132:/opt/exhibitor/conf /opt/exhibitor/conf/
root@machineC:/# sudo mount -t nfs 10.108.24.132:/opt/exhibitor/conf /opt/exhibitor/conf/
```

Did my `/etc/exports` file looks good? As I have the same content in all the three machines. And also are there any logs related to NFS which I can see to find any clues?

Any idea what wrong I am doing here?

**UPDATE:-**

So my `etc/exports` files would be like this in all the three machines -

```
# /etc/exports: the access control list for filesystems which may be exported
#               to NFS clients.  See exports(5).
#
# Example for NFSv2 and NFSv3:
# /srv/homes       hostname1(rw,sync,no_subtree_check) hostname2(ro,sync,no_subtree_check)
#
# Example for NFSv4:
# /srv/nfs4        gss/krb5i(rw,sync,fsid=0,crossmnt,no_subtree_check)
# /srv/nfs4/homes  gss/krb5i(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
#
/opt/exhibitor/conf/     10.108.24.132(rw)
/opt/exhibitor/conf/     10.108.24.133(rw)
/opt/exhibitor/conf/     10.108.24.134(rw)
```

Just a quick check - The IP Address that I am taking for each machine as mentioned above is like this -

```
root@machineB:/# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:ad:5b:a7
          inet addr:10.108.24.133  Bcast:10.108.27.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5696812 errors:0 dropped:12462 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5083427 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:7904369145 (7.9 GB)  TX bytes:601844910 (601.8 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:187144 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:187144 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:24012302 (24.0 MB)  TX bytes:24012302 (24.0 MB)
```

Here the IP Address that I am taking for machineB is `10.108.24.133`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to determine the other options along with the (rw) such as (rw,sync,fsid=0,crossmnt,no_subtree_check) etc. since they have their own meaning (explained in my article) and allow the hosts in /etc/hosts.allow

I will suggest you to take a quick look at this tutorial [How to Setup the NFS Server in Ubuntu](http://www.gurjap.org/nfs-server-in-ubuntu/) and if you have any question or concerns , please let me know.

Comment: Link is broken....

Comment: yes! sorry! My website crashed and I have lost all the data. I may have to write another post. You can tell me what problem do you have? I might be able to help you out

Comment: Thanks, but I'm actually not having a particular problem at the moment; I was just trying to figure out what settings to use.

Comment: I will post the link tomorrow, for you. thanks

Comment: I have fixed the broken link. Thanks or you can check it out at `http://www.gurjap.org/nfs-server-in-ubuntu/`

Comment: your welcome! Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Just had a quick glance over the exports manpage.  I think the wildcard '*' is only applicable for hostname-based exports.  If you wish to export to MachineB and MachineC, I would first try your export as:

```
10.108.24.0/24(rw)
```

..and see how that goes.  This will export to 10.108.24.1-254 (usable).  If this is definitely not what you want, try specifying each IP address separately:

```
10.108.24.133(rw) 10.108.24.134(rw)
```

cheers

sc.

Comment: I updated my question with updated exports file. Can you take a look whether that file will be like that after the change?

Comment: It looks good, but lose the trailing slash after conf; it's not required.  I also see you're using a /22, so if you did use the entire range to export to, it'd be: 10.108.24.0/22(rw)

Answer (score 0):

if you have the nfs file system then

1.install nfs-common  `sudo apt-get install nfs-common`

2.`sudo nano /etc/fstab` and type the following

server.me.lab:/path/to/folder /home/foo nfs rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr,noatime

3.make a mount point

```
mkdir /home/foo
```

4.`sudo mount -a`

Comment: Have you tried using vnc might work whit a script, and mount the three machines sda file system.